# Adding new Nuget Package Source by code within Visual Studio

Tags: c#, nuget, vsix, project-template, package-manager-console

I have created a project template and a VSIX including a wizard which will do some additional stuff before creating the project. Actually we have some custom nugets included in the project which urges the user to restore the nugets after the project was created.

The issue now is that some users (developers) do not have the correct package source configured.

Therefore I am looking for a way to add this particular package source after the project was created by the vsix for example in the "RunFinished" method of my wizard.

I know I can do this by calling:

```
dotnet nuget add source https://abc.de/index.json -n CustomNugets
```

But I'm not clear how to to this by code using for example the package manager console. Or can I achieve this just by using

```
System.Diagnostics.Process
```

and executing above command with

```
ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C " + MyCommand);
```

This did not seem to do the job :-/

Does anybody have a hint for me?

Comment: Have you considered including in the template a nuget.config file with the source configured?

Comment: I thought about this but then this file would be part of the project right? The problem is that this file should not show up in the project as part of it

Comment: Depending on the project type, it might show up in the project or not. It just needs to be in the folder to be used. Yes, unfortunately, you'd have a copy of it for each project. Granted, it's not an ideal solution but it might be a good stop-gap measure.

Comment: If you're using SDK-style projects, you would have to explicitly exclude it with `<None Remove="nuget.config" />` in an `ItemGroup`.

Comment: Thx, I will check and give feedback :)

Comment: Found a solution via coding ?

Comment: @BrilBroeder no, unfortunately not, sorry